# flutter - how to create forms in popup

Tags: flutter, dart, popup, flutter-layout, flutter-form-builder

I want to create a form inside a pop-up with flutter like the image below:
popup

[image: popup].

how can I do that with flutter?

Comment: Use `showDialog()` or `showGeneralDialog()`

Comment: showDialog(context: context , builder:  (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(height: 10.0 , width: 10.0, color: Colors.white,);})
I did this but a white page is shown. I want the popup to be a proportion of my page not all of it

Comment: You need to use `Wrap` or `Column` with `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Here you go! showDialog takes a WidgetBuilder as a parameter so you can return any widget.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await showDialog<void>(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                        content: Stack(
                          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Positioned(
                              right: -40,
                              top: -40,
                              child: InkResponse(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                                child: const CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                  child: Icon(Icons.close),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Form(
                              key: _formKey,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                    child: TextFormField(),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                    child: TextFormField(),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                      child: const Text('Submitß'),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                          _formKey.currentState!.save();
                                        }
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ));
            },
            child: const Text('Open Popup'),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Hop it helps!

Comment: @Amit From the docs:

The State for the widget in the tree that currently has this global key.
The current state is null if (1) there is no widget in the tree that matches this global key, (2) that widget is not a StatefulWidget, or the associated State object is not a subtype of T.

Comment: @AjayKumar can you please add close button ??

Comment: If we are using showDialog. AlertDialog is still required?

Comment: @NullByte08 From [the `showDialog` docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html): "_This function takes a builder which typically builds a Dialog widget_". In other words, `showDialog` is used to display dialog widgets like `AlertDialog`.

Comment: For those needing the 'overflow' parameter, with the latest updates you must replace it with `clipBehavior: Clip.none` [source](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gC5Di4ykTCqupD77PWpy9D8xXo0Ide5CnrH0zzVIhKo/")

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with current versions of Flutter.

Answer (score 16):

Here is an example of code that will allow you to create a button that can produce this kind of popup .

**Code** :

```
RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Open Popup"),
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    scrollable: true,
                    title: Text('Login'),
                    content: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Form(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Name',
                                icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
                              ),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Email',
                                icon: Icon(Icons.email),
                              ),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Message',
                                icon: Icon(Icons.message ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                     actions: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                          child: Text("Submit"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            // your code
                          })
                    ],
                  );
                });
          },
        ),
```

**Output :**

[image]

> For more options, you would have to manipulate the properties of the
> Form widget, the TextField widget or the RaisedButton widget such as
> autovalidation, decoration, color etc ... If this is not enough , you
> can use the [Dialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Dialog-class.html) widget instead of the [AlertDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) widget. But in
> this case, you will replace the content property with child. And make
> the necessary modifications.

Comment: How would you use the _formKey.validate from the RaisedButton inside actions?

Answer (score 9):

**Screenshot (without any 3rd party packages):**

[image]

---

**Code:** Just call this method:

```dart
void showDialogWithFields() {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      var emailController = TextEditingController();
      var messageController = TextEditingController();
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Contact Us'),
        content: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: emailController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email'),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: messageController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Message'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: Text('Cancel'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Send them to your email maybe?
              var email = emailController.text;
              var message = messageController.text;
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Text('Send'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: In case anyone face 'hasSize' error: Replace ListView with->
`content: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(....))`

Comment: AlertDialog takes a scrollable (false by default) parameter.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            content: Stack(
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  right: -15.0,
                  top: -15.0,
                  child: InkResponse(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 12,
                      child: Icon(Icons.close, size: 18,),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 60,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color:Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.2),
                          border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3))
                          )
                        ),
                        child: Center(child: Text("Contact Me", style:TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 20, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: "Helvetica"))),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 50,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2) )
                          ),
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex:1,
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: 30,
                                    child: Center(child: Icon(Icons.person, size: 35,color:Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4))),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        border: Border(
                                            right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2))
                                        )
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 4,
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        hintText: "Name",
                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left:20),
                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                        focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                        errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color:Colors.black26, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500 )
                                    ),

                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          child: Container(
                              width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              height: 60,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                               gradient: LinearGradient(
                                 begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                 end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                 colors: [
                                   Color(0xffc9880b),
                                   Color(0xfff77f00),
                                 ]
                               )
                            ),
                            child: Center(child: Text("Submit", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white70, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),)),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                              _formKey.currentState.save();
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried all answers above but it says no material Widget error. then I try this
in the place of the icon button, u can use any widget but u have to use  scaffold  bg Color as a transparent and back or cancel button too

```
onTap: () {
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return Scaffold(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  body: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
```