# white space covers the content when keyboard opens in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a singlechildscrollview inside a scaffold inside another scaffold, When keyboard pops out a white space appears and covers the content behind it. I tried using resizeToAvoidBottomInset =  false, it works but scroll view is not working in this , i want scroll view to also work
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1992], locale en-IN)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KAqs.png)

Comment: Please add your code so we can try it on our side and help you.

Comment: https://github.com/Rishavrajprasad/flutter-app  here is my github repository

Comment: You just need to move the `Scaffold` widget of SignUpScreen. Remove it and wrap it on Center widget who has the container as child, This will solve your problem of white space in opened keyboard.

Comment: Yes it worked but my  since my container has predefined width , Now when keyboard pops it's moving up and not staying in center and I wanted to keep scaffold under my container cause when tapping outside the container, pop us should close

Comment: Then why are you doing this all, you should use dialog box, it will be efficient to manage. Checkout this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54480641/flutter-how-to-create-forms-in-popup